# Unable to Create a method with Custom Name in Asp.Net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller Named "Product" in which I am writing a Method with custom Name "CategorizedProducts" as shown in this 
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaGqH.png). I have not decorated it with [HttpGet]. When I request this action/method in chrome,  [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OthTq.png) error is occurred. Routes from WebAPIConfig.cs are given below:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Below two Routes are also there in Routes.cs file:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please help me how to get rid of this error and successfully get data by using CategorizedProducts Method name. 
Thanks

Comment: Step 1: add `[HttpGet]`. Step 2: change `cat_id` to `id`. Step 3: remove those useless route configurations from your api (`ApiWithAction` is never used) and MVC (`DefaultApi2` is clearly a Web API route, it has nothing to do inside `Routes.cs`). Also, **always post the code, never post a screenshot of the code**.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma nailed it

Comment: Got it back to work. Thanks :)